# How can I `SUM()` in PostgreSQL based on certain condition? For summing debits and credits in accounting journal table

Tags: postgresql

I have a database full with accounting journals. There is table for accounting journal itself (the accounting journal's metadata) and there is a table for accounting journal line (for each account with its debit or credit).

I have database like this:

```
+----+---------------+--------+---------+
| ID |  JOURNAL_NAME |  DEBIT |  CREDIT |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+
|    |               |        |         |
| 1  |  INV/0001     |  100   |  0      |
|    |               |        |         |
| 2  |  INV/0001     |  0     |  100    |
|    |               |        |         |
| 3  |  INV/0002     |  200   |  0      |
|    |               |        |         |
| 4  |  INV/0002     |  0     |  200    |
+----+---------------+--------+---------+
```

I want to have all journal with the same name to be summed in one, their debits and credits. So from the above table... I want to have a query that makes something like this:

```
+--------------+--------+---------+
| JOURNAL_NAME |  DEBIT |  CREDIT |
+--------------+--------+---------+
|              |        |         |
| INV/0001     |  100   |  100    |
|              |        |         |
| INV/0002     |  200   |  200    |
+--------------+--------+---------+
```

I have tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accounting_journal.id)
    accounting_journal.name,
    accounting_journal_line.debit,
    accounting_journal_line.credit
FROM accounting_journal_line
JOIN accounting_journal ON accounting_journal.id = accounting_journal_line.move_id
ORDER BY accounting_journal.id ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

With the above query, I have all the journal and the journal lines. I just need to have the above query to sum the debits and credits for every same `accounting_journal.name`.

I have tried with `SUM()` but it always stuck in GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accounting_journal.id)
    accounting_journal.name,
    accounting_journal.ref,
    accounting_journal_line.name,
    SUM(accounting_journal_line.debit),
    SUM(accounting_journal_line.credit)
FROM accounting_journal_line
JOIN accounting_journal ON accounting_journal.id = accounting_journal_line.move_id
ORDER BY accounting_journal.id ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

The error:

```
Error in query (7): ERROR: column "accounting_journal.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: accounting_journal.name,
```

I hope I can get assistance or pointer where I need to look at, here. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that simply `select name, sum(debit), sum(credit) ... group by name;`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using any aggregation function with normal columns then your have to mention all the non-aggregating column in group by clause,

So try This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accounting_journal.id)
    accounting_journal.name,
    accounting_journal.ref,
    accounting_journal_line.name,
    SUM(accounting_journal_line.debit),
    SUM(accounting_journal_line.credit)
FROM accounting_journal_line
JOIN accounting_journal ON accounting_journal.id = accounting_journal_line.move_id
group by 1,2,3
ORDER BY accounting_journal.id ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

In your query you are having 3 non-aggregation column so you can mention column number in group by clause to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sum [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), it does not require "group by". So:

```
select aj.id    journal_id 
       aj.name  journal_name,
       aj.ref   journal_ref,
       ajl.name line_name,
       sum(ajl.debit)  over(partition by aj.id) total_debit,
       sum(ajl.credit) over(partition by aj.id) total_credit
from accounting_journal_line ajl
join accounting_journal aj 
  on aj.id = ajl.move_id
order by aj.id;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4cbef635f697fb2c4083bb030cdb413) for a working example.